# Should injected dependencies be readonly fields or private properties

Tags: c#

We have a small disagreement within my team over whether injected dependencies should be stored as readonly fields:

```
public class MyClient
{
    private readonly IService service;
    public MyClient(IService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }
 }
```

or as private readonly properties:

```
public class MyClient
{
    private IService Service { get; }
    public MyClient(IService service)
    {
        Service = service;
    }
 }
```

Are there any advantages to one choice over the other? I favour the former but it seems half of our classes use the latter.

Comment: Readonly fields. There is no reason to use a property here.

Comment: They are the same: both private (so invisible outside the class, so no extra coupling and could be refactored between each other any time), both are assignable only in constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a readonly field.

The are three reasons to use properties over fields:

1. You want to add some extra logic which is run when the property is accessed.
2. You want to reserve the right to add some extra logic in the future, without changing your interface.
3. You're using some tool / serialization framework which only deals with properties, and ignores fields.

Point 2 is why people recommend using properties instead of fields for all public (and sometimes protected) members. Point 1 (and perhaps point 3, in rare cases) is the only reason you would create a private property.

None of those points apply here. The property is only adding extra overhead, and there's no reason to pay that cost for zero gain.

Comment: CodeLens doesn't seem to work with fields. When I am re-factoring code to remove unnecessary dependencies, it's easier to spot injected services, that is no longer in use, if I use getter-properties (having ref. count = 1) instead of read-only fields.

Answer (score 1):

I think `readonly` field is the safest approach as it prevents you from creating a new instance of the field in a different place than the constructor(Single Responsibility Principle). The decision what kind of implementation for interfaces should be used in a given class should be done at the level of the DI container. You can inject different objects for different environments, based on the app settings in your Continuous Delivery pipeline. Though you don't have to worry about weird things like e.g. using some `AzureSerive` when using OnPremise version of the app etc.

Comment: How is it more safe to use a `private readonly int x;` than `private int X { get; }` if we only want to set it from the constructor? (Or, possible `private int X { get; init }`.)

Answer (score -1):

[Using a private readonly property with a getter or a private readonly field is equivalent in term of generated bytecode, so it's just a matter of taste.] <-- this is not true, as pointed below. Sorry for the inconvenience.

I prefer (and use) private fields, as I consider them more clear semantically (in my mind a field is private, fullstop) and less verbose (no need for that awful { get; }, I hate getters ).

Comment: "*equivalent in term of generated bytecode*" -- not true, the property generates the backing field, **plus** a property which wraps it. [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxASwDYB8ACAmARgFgAoHAZgAJ9KBhSgb1MpcoAcE0A3CeShOBAAmAewB2GAJ7UCABkoQA3M1YduvODPnBGlAOZwYiygF9SJoA=)

Comment: Yes, you're true. Automatic properties generates automatically backing fields, so using them or writing your own backing field ala C# < 3.0 is the same. Automatic properties are just syntactic sugar.  
I don't know why I wrote that other thing, sorry :|

Comment: Perhaps I'm misreading. You point out that it's **not** a matter of taste in the first paragraph. Then, in the second one, you say that you **prefer** and **hate**. Isn't that **precisely** a reference to taste? Help me understand.